# How to make parallax effect if not with background-attachment?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Found this for parallax effect: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

They use `background-attachment: fixed;`

If you check the first section here, there is parallax effect applied, but no `background-attachment` is used: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/

```html
<section id="section_5ZtkF" class="section-image hc-cmp-section  light  section-bottom-layer  ken-burn-center" data-parallax="scroll" data-natural-height="1080" data-natural-width="1920" data-position="" data-image-src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg">
```

I guess it is done with jQuery? Effect is triggered with parameter: `data-parallax="scroll"` Also image is passed with `data-image-src` parameter.

Does one solution have any advantage over the other approach?

I did check all the css, and no `background-attachment` found at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do a parallax effect, but it mostly depends on the parallax effect you're looking for.

If you want two divs moving at a different speed, you'll probably need to use Javascript, or a package that will do it for you. Here's a link to a package that will add parallax to a div: [parallax.js](https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

If you want a parallax effect where only one div move (as in the first exemple you sent), you can use CSS.

In the first exemple, a background is set to a div that has `position: fixed` (meaning the div won't move when scrolling). Then, other div will hide the background image when scrolling creating a parallax effect.